# Very Basic SQL Making Page Bomb

Tags: php

So I'm training in MVC and extending functionality from a tutorial.  I'm not getting any echos after "SUBMITTED: " with each of the values for binding.  I double-checked and ran the query in PHPMyAdmin and it's inserting fine.  The page is just bombing as soon as I call $this->query and I don't understand why.  In the add function that's bombing, I'm trying to add a List Item.  List Items (like Vacuum) belong to a List (like Cleaning).  The class where I add Lists is EXACTLY the same and works perfectly.

```
  public function add(){
         // Sanitize POST
         $post = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

     // show the List name
     $lModel = new ListModel();
     $lName = $lModel->getListTitle($this->listID);

         if($post['submit']){
             echo "SUBMITTED: Name: " . $post['name'] . " ID: " . $this->listID . " And 1 for Position<br>";

            // Insert
            $this->query("INSERT into list_item (list_id, name, position) VALUES (:list_id, :name, :position)");
            echo "After query<br>";
            $this->bind(':list_id', $this->listID);
            $this->bind(':name', $post['name']);
            $this->bind(':position', 1);
            echo "After binding<br>";
            //Verify
            $this->execute();
            echo "Execute?<br>";
            if($this->lastInsertId()){
                echo "Insert ID " . $this->lastInsertId();
               //redirect
               //header("Location: " .ROOT_URL."listItems/index/" . $this->listID);
            }else{
                echo "Didn't insert<br>";
                Messages::setMsg('Failed to insert list','error');
            }
         }
//echo "lName: $lName";
         return $lName;
      }
}
```

Here is the entire class for your viewing pleasure.

```
<?php

class ListItemModel extends Model{

      public $listID;

      public function __construct($id){
             $this->listID = $id;
      }

      public function Index(){
          return "some data";
         $this->query("SELECT * FROM list_item WHERE list_id = :list_id ORDER BY create_dt DESC");
         $this->bind(':list_id', $this->listID);
         $rows = $this->resultSet();
         return $rows;
      }

      public function add(){
         // Sanitize POST
         $post = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

     // show the List name
     $lModel = new ListModel();
     $lName = $lModel->getListTitle($this->listID);

         if($post['submit']){
             echo "SUBMITTED: Name: " . $post['name'] . " ID: " . $this->listID . " And 1 for Position<br>";

            // Insert
            $this->query("INSERT into list_item (list_id, name, position) VALUES (:list_id, :name, :position)");
            echo "After query<br>";
            $this->bind(':list_id', $this->listID);
            $this->bind(':name', $post['name']);
            $this->bind(':position', 1);
            echo "After binding<br>";
            //Verify
            $this->execute();
            echo "Execute?<br>";
            if($this->lastInsertId()){
                echo "Insert ID " . $this->lastInsertId();
               //redirect
               //header("Location: " .ROOT_URL."listItems/index/" . $this->listID);
            }else{
                echo "Didn't insert<br>";
                Messages::setMsg('Failed to insert list','error');
            }
         }
//echo "lName: $lName";
         return $lName;
      }
}


?>
```

And here's the query function in Model as requested

```
public function query($query){
    $this->stmt = $this->dbh->prepare($query);
}
```

Comment: Can you show your query function, please?

Comment: you can always catch the errors:

`try{$this->execute();} catch (\Throwable $t) {var_dump($t);}` or you can place the whole query into try/catch.

What does the error say?

Comment: Maybe `(:list_id, :name, :position)` needs to be `(:list_id, ':name', :position)`?

Comment: @Peter Placeholders should not be quoted, otherwise it would think it's a string instead of a placeholder.

Comment: @aynber the error it's giving me is "Call to a member function prepare() on null"  What does this mean?  I'm extending the Model class to ListItemModel, just like I did with ListModel.  Why is this breaking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out!!!

Because I was using the constructor in ListItemModel (which extends Model) to pass in the $id for the list, I needed `parent::__construct()`.

Thanks, everyone!